# Repository not injected in service class when initialized through a factory class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, factory-pattern

I have multiple implementations for a method, so I decided to use Factory design pattern for it. Here is the implementation for factory class:

```
@Component
public class ProcessFileFactory {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public ProcessFileFactory() {
        applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                ProcessDoctorFile.class,
                ProcessPatientFile.class
        );
    }

    public static ProcessImportFiles getInstance(String fileType) {
        if (ImportTypes.DOCTORS.toString().equals(fileType)) {
            return applicationContext.getBean("processDoctorFile", ProcessImportFiles.class);
        }
        if (ImportTypes.PATIENTS.toString().equals(fileType)) {
            return applicationContext.getBean("processPatientFile", ProcessImportFiles.class);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

ProcessImportFiles is the interface where I defined the method which has to be implemented differently. And here is one implementation of the method from the interface:

```
@Service
public class ProcessDoctorFile implements ProcessImportFiles {
    @Autowired
    private DoctorRepository doctorRepository;

    @Override
    public void processImportFile(String fileName, Sheet sheet) {
        System.out.println("doctors");
    }
}
```

Also, this is how I call the the method in the rest controller:

```
 ProcessFileFactory.getInstance(fileType).processImportFile(file.getName(), sheet);
```

But I receive this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processFileFactory' defined in file [C:\Workspace\MedicalStatistics\target\classes\app\one\MedicalStatistics\importService\ProcessFileFactory.class]: Failed to instantiate [app.one.MedicalStatistics.importService.ProcessFileFactory]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at app.one.MedicalStatistics.MedicalStatisticsApplication.main(MedicalStatisticsApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [app.one.MedicalStatistics.importService.ProcessFileFactory]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:223) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'processDoctorFile': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'doctorRepository': No qualifying bean of type 'app.one.MedicalStatistics.repository.DoctorRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at app.one.MedicalStatistics.importService.ProcessFileFactory.<init>(ProcessFileFactory.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:197) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'app.one.MedicalStatistics.repository.DoctorRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1812) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1371) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

If I comment the declaration for DoctorRepository the application starts and design pattern works as expected. The problem appeared when I defined a repo in my service for updating data in DB. I tried to create a constructor to initialize the repository, also multiple annotations, but nothing works. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some details that could be important are missing in your question (packages of the classes involved in your problem, for example) but I guess that, for any reason, the ApplicationContext you instantiate in your ProcessFileFactory does not discover the DoctorRepository class.

I suggest to change your factory this way :

```
    @Component
    public class ProcessFileFactory implements org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware {

        private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        public static ProcessImportFiles getInstance(String fileType) {
            if (ImportTypes.DOCTORS.toString().equals(fileType)) {
                return applicationContext.getBean("processDoctorFile", ProcessImportFiles.class);
            }
            if (ImportTypes.PATIENTS.toString().equals(fileType)) {
                return applicationContext.getBean("processPatientFile", ProcessImportFiles.class);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
            throws BeansException {
            this.applicationContext = context;
        }
    }
```

When you implement ApplicationContextAware interface, you ask Spring to inject into your class the existing application context.

But, to be honest, there is a solution that, I think, would be cleaner as it would just use Dependency Injection instead of getting beans from the application context.

Change your `ProcessImportFiles` this way :

```
    public interface ProcessImportFiles {

      String getManagedFileType();

      void processImportFile(String fileName, Sheet sheet);

    }
```

Implementation example of the interface for `ProcessPatientFile`:

```
@Service
public class ProcessPatientFile implements ProcessImportFiles {

    @Override
    public String getManagedFileType() {
        return ImportTypes.PATIENTS.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void processImportFile(String fileName, Sheet sheet) {

        System.out.println("I'm processing a PATIENTS file");

    }
}
```

Then change your `ProcessFileFactory` class this way :

```
    @Component
    public class ProcessFileFactory {

      private Map<String, ProcessImportFiles> importFileProcessorsByType;

      public ProcessFileFactory(Collection<ProcessImportFiles> importFileProcessors) {

        importFileProcessorsByType = importFileProcessors.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            ProcessImportFiles::getManagedFileType,
            processor -> processor
        ));

      }

      public ProcessImportFiles getInstance(String fileType) {
        return importFileProcessorsByType.get(fileType);
      }

    }
```

Spring will automatically inject all beans implementing your interface into your factory. The internal map of your factory will retrieve the expected implementation according to the fileType.

By the way, if one day, you need to code new implementations of the `ProcessImportFiles` interface, your factory will work without any change.

Comment: No problem :) Please have a look at my edited answer, I think there is a better solution than using the ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code and struct it again to look more readable, this is how I proceeded:

First, this is the structure:

[image]

Assuming this is your ProcessDoctorFile service:

```
@Service
public class ProcessDoctorFileService implements ProcessImportFiles {
    @Autowired
    private DoctorRepository doctorRepository;

    @Override
    public void processImportFile(String fileName, Sheet sheet) {
        System.out.println(fileName + " > ProcessDoctorFileService");
    }
}
```

same thing for the patient service:

```
@Service
public class ProcessPatientFileService implements ProcessImportFiles {
    @Autowired
    private PatientRepository doctorRepository;

    @Override
    public void processImportFile(String fileName, Sheet sheet) {
        System.out.println(fileName + " > ProcessPatientFileService");
    }
}
```

Now the factory:

```
public class ProcessFileFactory   {
    public static ProcessImportFiles getInstance(String fileType) {
        if (ImportTypes.DOCTORS.toString().equals(fileType)) {
            return ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("processDoctorFileService", ProcessImportFiles.class);
        }
        if (ImportTypes.PATIENTS.toString().equals(fileType)) {
            return ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("processPatientFileService", ProcessImportFiles.class);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

To be sure that you don't get a null application context, you should get it in another class and then inject it into your factory, use ApplicationContextAware interface to make spring boot provide the application context for you:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ApplicationContextProvider.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

let's test what we did until now using a CommandLineRunner:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StackoverflowApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(){
        return args -> {
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
            ProcessFileFactory.getInstance(ImportTypes.DOCTORS.name()).processImportFile("file name for doctors",sheet);
            ProcessFileFactory.getInstance(ImportTypes.PATIENTS.name()).processImportFile("file name for patients",sheet);
        };
    }

}
```

Result in the console:
[image]